# How can I have a non-global (locally scoped) shared library for a declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I would like to define some groovy code that is imported into one or more declarative pipelines that are all stored in the same git repo.

I do *NOT* want to create a global shared library that different pipelines from different repos share.

For example, in a repo I might have the following files:

```
shared-library.groovy
pr-pipeline-unit-tests.groovy
pr-pipeline-ui-tests.groovy
```

I want both `pr-pipeline-unit-tests.groovy`  and `pr-pipeline-ui-tests.groovy` to be able to import `shared-library.groovy`.

These pipelines are executed on PRs, and updates to `shared-library.groovy` should only affect that PR - this is why I do not want a jenkins globally stored shared library.

As bonus, it would be cool if `shared-library.groovy` could be a standalone gradle project that is "imported" into the pipelines, similar to how `buildSrc` is imported into gradle project configuration files. Even better if the shared code could be Kotlin!

Comment: If you do not want the library to be global, then you would import it for the pipeline and not in the master configuration, use a folder library, etc. Have you seen the documentation for shared library usage https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries? Do you need something beyond what is documented?

Comment: @MattSchuchard can I have this "non-global" shared library be a part of the same git repo where the my `pipeline.groovy` files live?

Comment: Documentation implies yes: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#folder-level-shared-libraries